# Is it possible to specify a "not equals" condition whilst defining Load Balancer rules for path based routing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm trying to add path based routing in an AWS Load Balancer. [image]

In the above screenshot, the rule specifies "my_path" as the matching rule. Is there anyway to specify routing based on a path *not matching* a particular pattern, instead of matching?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: A very specific scenario concerning 2 lbs, one for an admin site and one for a public facing site - not particularly important. I just need to know is it possible or not

Comment: The listener already has a "default" logic, which is used if none of the rules are matched (or if there are no rules)

Comment: Yep, I've a default rule set already. I just want to know is it possible to set a specific rule with a "not" condition.